# Проблема в установке Laravel через Openserver

Tags: laravel, composer, openserver

после Установки Composer в командной строке ввёл 
  composer global require "laravel/installer"
 Выдало следующий результат:

Changed current directory to C:/Users/VipBeLL/AppData/Roaming/Composer
  Using version ^2.0 for laravel/installer./composer.json has been updated
  Loading composer repositories with package information
  Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
  Package operations: 10 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.2): Downloading (failed)
   Downloading (failed)
   Downloading (failed)
   Failed to download symfony/process from dist: The 
 "https://api.github.com/repos/symfony/process/zipball/1d1677391ecf00d1c5b9482d6050c0c27aa3ac3a" file could not be downloaded: SSL operation failed with code 1. 
   OpenSSL Error messages:
   error:1416F086:SSL routines:tls_process_server_certificate:certificate verify 
   failed
Failed to enable crypto
failed to open stream: operation failed
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing symfony/process (v4.1.2): Cloning 1d1677391e

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/symfony/process.git via https, ssh protocol
  s, aborting.

- https://github.com/symfony/process.git
  Cloning into 'C:\Users\VipBeLL\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\proce
  ss'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/symfony/process.git/': SSL certi
  ficate problem: self signed certificate in certificate chain
- git@github.com:symfony/process.git
  Cloning into 'C:\Users\VipBeLL\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\symfony\proce
  ss'...
  Host key verification failed.
  fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

  Please make sure you have the correct access rights
  and the repository exists.

подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том, что  загрузку содержимого блокировал антивирусник ( в моём случае Касперский). Поэтому, перед загрузкой следует отключить все антивирусники (в том числе и защитника Windows), либо добавить антивируснику в исключения активность того элемента (в моём случае php), который отвечает за/влияет на загрузку.

Answer (score 0):

1)
браузер открывает ссылки, перечисленные в ошибке?
установлены ли расширения?
читались ли манулы?

http://laravel.su/docs/5.4/installation

- PHP >= 5.6.4
- Расширение PHP OpenSSL
- Расширение PHP PDO
- Расширение PHP Mbstring
- Расширение PHP Tokenizer
- Расширение PHP XML

---

2)
для чего "козе боян" Openserver

http://laravel.su/docs/4.1/quick

> Запуск веб-сервера
>
> Обычно для запуска приложения Laravel нужно, чтобы в системе стоял веб-сервер - Apache или Nginx. Но если вы работаете с PHP версии 5.4 или выше , вы можете запустить встроенный в PHP веб-сервер следующей командой:

```
php artisan serve
```